# Coldbox module event dying in renderLayout call

Tags: module, coldfusion, coldbox

**tl;dr**: `renderLayout(layout="myLayout", view="alpha/bravo/viewFile")` resolves `alpha` as a module name rather than a package name in the host application, even if code execution is in the package rather than the module.

**How do I get the path resolution to be consistent when either running the handler directly or when calling it via `runEvent` from a module?**

---

I posted this on the CB google group, but then thought it may be best to ask here.

Working example here: https://github.com/jinglesthula/cbModuleExample

If you run install (I .gitignored the coldbox folder), then `cd` into the `/app` folder and `server start --rewritesEnable` you can visit `http://127.0.0.1:<whatever port>/example/admin/test/ajax` to see it in action.

---

From the example:

`/app/modules_app/example/handlers/admin/test.cfc -> ajax()` calls `runEvent("admin.test.ajax")`

`/app/handlers/admin/test.cfc -> ajax()` calls `renderLayout( layout = "layout.div", view = "admin/test/ajax" )

`"admin/test/ajax"` normally resolves to `/app/views/admin/test/ajax.cfm`, but in this case it's resolving to `/app/modules_app/admin/views/test/ajax.cfm`.

You can comment out line 18 and uncomment line 19 in `/modules_app/example/admin/handlers/test.cfc` to see a workaround.

You can also go to `/admin/test/ajaxDirect` in your browser to see that the `renderLayout()` call in the non-working example is correct.

*Note: I have `this.viewParentLookup = true` in my ModuleConfig.cfc.  I've tried reloading the module with it set to false and I get the same result.*

Comment: Hi, this is all a lot to follow.  Can you throw together a simple example app that demonstrates the issue and commit it to a GitHub rep?. Then, anyone can clone it, start up a server in CommandBox, and see just what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry - it is quite a bit.  I edited the question and included a link to the github repo at the top of it.  The code there is slightly simplified from the question (I put the module in `modules_app` rather than trying for a completely separate location), but demonstrates the issue in action.

Comment: @BradWood I boiled it down to just the question, link/instructions for the example repo, and the pertinent info.

Comment: Thanks, I'm super busy at our Into The Box conference this week so I won't be able to take a look for a couple more days.

Comment: @BradWood no worries - and good luck w/ the conference.  Wish I could be there